# How could I manage to display content from table inside a view that belongs to a seperate controller/model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Basically, if I have a table in controller A which I wanted to display in a view belonging to controller B how would I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a partial located at `app/views/controllera/_partial.html.erb` containing your table, the partial can be rendered from a view like `app/views/controllerb/some_action.html.erb` as follows

```
<%= render partial: "controllera/partial", locals: { ... } %>
```

Comment: Tried but im getting a missing partial error Missing partial /apartments/aptMenu with {:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:coffee, :erb, :builder], :locale=>[:en]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/raphaelshejnberg/LiveWell/app/views"

Comment: You need to provide more that one sentence of information in future questions; it will help get your questions resolved faster. What is the exact name and path of the partial you're trying to access?